# Highcharts tooltip dateTimeLabelFormats shows wrong format

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I use highcharts to show some charts recently, I was using the tooltip for my project. Here is my configure:

```
tooltip:{
                    shared:true,
                    crosshairs:true,
                    dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                        hour:"%m-%e %H:%M",
                        day:"%m-%e",
                        month:"%Y-%m",
                    },
                },
```

So my question is:
How can highcharts know which format to choose in the tooltip?
Highcharts can choose the correct format for hour and day, but when I want to show a month format data, it still use the day format, what should I do?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean month-format-data? You have one point per month to use that dateTime format? Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/80gnnsq9/ - works fine. If you want different logic for dateTimeLabelFormats then you need to use [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).

Comment: Keep in mind that it only uses the month format if the data range needs it to be. If your data is within a month it only uses the day  and/or the hour format.

Comment: @PawełFus The jsfiddle code is really helpful!